# can't install wxPython on Anaconda Python

Tags: wxpython, anaconda, gnuradio

I installed Anaconda Python on my RHEL6 system. In order to run gnuradio I need wxPython. For that reason I did

```
conda install wxpython
```

The problem is when I try to import Wx module in python. Then the following error arises:

```
>>> import wx
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/scr1/nemanja/install/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
from wx._core import *
File "/scr1/nemanja/install/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
import _core_
ImportError: /scr1/nemanja/install/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-gtk2/wx/../../../../libwx_gtk2u-3.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_malloc_n
```

What is missing here?

Comment: you only need wxpython if you want to use the GNU Radio wx gui components, which are deprecated by now.

Comment: I installed a custom Python module that needs `wx` with `~/anaconda/bin/pip`, which also installed the prerequisites. Sadly, this has fallen over with the same error as the one reported here. I then installed `wx` independently with `~/anaconda/bin/conda install wxpython`, and it works like a charm. wxpython-4.0.4 , Python 3.7.6

Answer (score 5):

I had a small python script that used wx many years ago, and recently started using anaconda. Then, I faced the same issue when I tried to run the script with the anaconda python as it didn't include the wx package. To try sorting out the issue, what I did is:

> > binstar search -t conda wxpython

Which will list up the name (i.e., wxpython), version, type and platform. Select the right version for you when using the command:

> > conda install -c anaconda wxpython=(version)

In which 3.0 for (version) works for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar problem installing WX on Anaconda.

The system was running Windows 7, Anaconda 4.3.22 and needed to install wxPython 4.0.0a2.

```
#Did'nt work in my case.
$conda install -c anaconda wxpython=(version)
```

I'm not exactly sure why this didn't work but the error message reported that the dependencies were incorrect. The wxpython was expecting Python 2 and Anaconda is running Python 3.

However, the issue was resolved by running the following from the "Anaconda Prompt".

```
$conda install -c melund wxpython=4.0.0a2
```

Here's some [more documentation](https://anaconda.org/melund/wxpython) for anyone interested or more knowledgeable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need wx to build GNU Radio -- most people are steering away from WX in favor of the Qt Widgets, which have largely superseeded the WX functionality. That being said, if you *rely* on anything that uses wx:

Now, it seems that anaconda's version of wxpython is broken. I'd say: ignore and uninstall that, simply use the one that you should be available via EPEL. It will work better, especially since GNU Radio will probably have a better time linking against things that are properly installed using `yum`/`rpm`.

Comment: Well I did install gnuradio only with qtgui support, but I am not able to run filter_design which is very important for me.

Comment: @Nexy_sm: I can understand that. Looks like you'll really need to install `yum install wxPython-devel` ,  from EPEL, rebuild GNU Radio with gr-wxgui support enabled, and try again!